# how to retrieve datas from database and put them into a multidimensionnal array

Tags: java, swing

i wanted to retrieve all my datas from database and display them in a jtable, i did the retrieving method that return a vector,i displayed them and it worked. but when i want now to create a model that my jtable will use it seems that the model only takes a multidimensionnal array (Object[][] object). the problem is that it was eazy for me to retrive datas and put them in a vector, but now with a multidimensionnal array (Object[][] object) i don't know how to put datas in it and to modify my method so that it return a multidimensionnal array, here is my retrieving method that returns a vector:

```
     @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
 public static Vector recupererListeEtudiant() 
    {
    Vector vec=new Vector<>();

        try {
            connexion = DriverManager.getConnection(url, login, password);
            statement = connexion.createStatement();
            resultat=statement.executeQuery("select * from Etudiant"); 


            while(resultat.next())
            {
                Vector ligne=new Vector<>();
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(1));
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(2));
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(3));
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(4));
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(5));
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(6));
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(7));
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(8));
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(9));
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(10));
                ligne.add(resultat.getString(11));

                vec.add(ligne);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    return vec;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> "it seems that the model only takes a multidimensionnal array (Object[][] object)."

Have you read the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html)? There's other constructors. You can construct it with vectors.

You can also construct a [`DefaultTableModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) with 0 rows

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefualtTableModel(columnNames, 0); // 0 rows
```

Then you can use `model.addRow(VectorOrArrayRow)`. After iterating set the model of the table.

```
table.setModel(model);
```

See more at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use [DefaultTableModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html#DefaultTableModel%28java.util.Vector,%20java.util.Vector%29) or implement AbstractTableModel